# Distance between chapter title and text

Tags: spacing, sectioning, chapters, koma-script, parskip

In my `scrreprt` I've changed distance between paragraphs with `\setlength{\parskip}{9pt}`. But `\parskip` changes also distance between chapter title and the paragraph.

How can I change distance between chapter title and the paragraph?

Answer (score 18):

The [`titlesec` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) provides

```
\titlespacing{<command>}{<left>}{<before-sep>}{<after-sep>}[<right>]
```

that allows for the spacing around any sectional `<command>` (like `\part`, `\chapter`, `\section`, etc.). The former two sectional commands require the additional `\titleformat` to be used (see the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf)). Consequently, altering `<after-sep>` should suit your needs.

The following minimal example, altered for `<after-sep>` equal to `\parskip`, `5\baselineskip` and `150pt` illustrates the changes (from left to right):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{titlesec}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum

\titleformat{\chapter}{\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptername\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\vskip 20pt\raggedright}%
% Alter <after-sep> in the macro below to vary the separation after the \chapter title.
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{<after-sep>}% \titlespacing{<command>}{<left>}{<before-sep>}{<after-sep>}[<right>]
\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image: Different spacings from chapter title using titlesec]

The [`lipsum` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) merely provides some dummy text, *Lorem Ipsum* style.

Comment: This is great but, as you can see in your example, this has erroneously added horizontal space before the first paragraph of text. How do I get rid of that?

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn: See [Cancelling first-line indents after section titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36722/5764): `\usepackage[noindentafter]{titlesec}`

Answer (score 13):

Don't change the `\parskip` length, but use the class option `parskip=full`. (This will, among other things, remove the now redundant indention of paragraphs.) If you don't want the "additional" parskip immediately after a chapter heading, change the `\chapterheadendvskip` macro.

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrreprt}

\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{%
  \vspace{0.725\baselineskip plus 0.115\baselineskip minus 0.192\baselineskip}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

(The [blindtext](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/blindtext/) package is only used to add some dummy text to the example.)

EDIT: My redefinition of `\chapterheadendvskip` resembles the original one, except that I replaced `1.725\baselineskip` with `0.725\baselineskip`. Hopefully, this will exactly offset the space added by `parskip=full`.

Answer (score 7):

The `\renewcommand` should go into the preamble. It is here only for demonstration inside the text.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrreprt}
\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}
bar

\setlength\parskip{40pt}
\renewcommand*\chapterheadendvskip{\vspace{-\normalbaselineskip}}    
\chapter{foo}
bar

baz
\end{document}
```