# Cancelling first-line indents after section titles

Tags: sectioning, indentation, paragraphs

Another probably very simple formatting question!

Is it possible to define a rule that maintains first-line indents in general, but flushes left the first paragraph following a section heading? Including the first paragraph of the whole paper, immediately following title and author declarations?

**EDIT:**

Ok, here's my current header. I'm not sure what would be throwing this off.

```
\documentclass[11pt,article,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setromanfont{Palatino}
\setsansfont{Helvetica}
\setmonofont{Monaco}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{} % Clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyhead[LO]{\slshape \rightmark}
    \fancyhead[RO]{$author$}
    \fancyfoot[CO]{\thepage}

% Format section titles
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section} 
  {\normalfont}{\thesection}{1.2em}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\titlespacing{\section}
  {0pt}{*6}{*2}

% Add a space after the footnote mark
\makeatletter%
\long\def\@makefnmark{%
\hbox {\@textsuperscript {\normalfont \@thefnmark \ }}}%
\makeatother

\usepackage{biblatex}
$if(biblio-files)$
    \bibliography{$biblio-files$}
$endif$

\usepackage{enumerate}

$if(numbersections)$
$else$
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
$endif$

$for(header-includes)$
$header-includes$
$endfor$

$if(title)$     \title{$title$}     $endif$
$if(author)$    \author{$for(author)$$author$$sep$\\$endfor$} $endif$
$if(date)$      \date{$date$}       $endif$

\begin{document}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Ok, I've isolated the culprit: the `\titlespacing` declaration. When I cut those two lines, the problem is fixed. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Error : Not enough memory!

Comment: The is the default behaviour of all standard LaTeX document classes. You must be doing something different (loading a package or using a different document class) to have to require this. Please elaborate.

Comment: @werner: surely we need an mwe from the op?

Comment: Ok, I've added my current header. Do you see anything that would be overriding the default format?

Comment: (The if-then statements are there because this is actually a template I use in conjunction with pandoc.)

Comment: This will surely give non indented first paragraphs. We need to see whether you load polyglossia (or babel) and with what language.

Comment: @egreg How do I check on that? Again, I'm running all of this through pandoc's `markdown2pdf` function, so I never manually call LaTeX at all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you are using the `titlesec` package with the explicit option, it seems that you need to specify explicitly whether there is no indent after headings.  You can do this with the package option `[noindentafter]`:

```
\usepackage[explicit,noindentafter]{titlesec}
```

Alternatively, as @egreg notes, you can use the starred version of the `\titlespacing` command:

```
\titlespacing*{\section}
   {0pt}{*6}{*2}
```

Comment: Or with `\titlespacing*` instead of `\titlespacing`.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using package [indentfirst](http://ctan.org/pkg/indentfirst) just don't use it. If you are using package [babel](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel) with option `french` add `\StandardLayout` to you preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\StandardLayout
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

and have a look at the package's manual to learn more about special features of French language definition.

If nothing of this helps, add

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \expandafter\def\csname @afterindentfalse\endcsname{%
    \expandafter\let\csname if@afterindent\endcsname\iffalse
  }%
}
```

to your document preamble and hope, that this would help. If it doesn't, try to move those lines just before `\begin{document}`. If this doesn't help, maybe you are using a class with hard coded indent after headings.