# Section Styles: Spacing, Font and Paragraph-Indentation

Tags: fonts, spacing, indentation, titlesec, sectsty

I am using `sectsty` to configure my section styles. I have read that perhaps `titlesec` is more powerful. A solution to my question below using `titlesec` is completely satisfactory.

Currently I am setting the fonts for `section` and `subsection` as follows.

```
\sectionfont{%                      % Change font of \section command
    \noindent
    \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}%       % bch-b-n: CharterBT-Bold font
    \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{2pt}}

\subsectionfont{\noindent\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}}
```

I am then adjusting the spacing as follows.

```
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
    {\bigskipamount}%
    {\bigskipamount}%
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries\SS@sectfont}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
    {\bigskipamount}%
    {\medskipamount}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\SS@subsectfont}}
```

The template for this adjustment comes from this SE question:
[How to adjust the title spacing using sectsty package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381256/how-to-adjust-the-title-spacing-using-sectsty-package).
A somewhat equivalent template for `titlesec` can be found from this SE question:
[Reducing spacing after headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53338/reducing-spacing-after-headings).

Now my issue is the following.
When I do this `\renewcommand\section...`, the first paragraph is indented. I don't want this.
With `titlesec`, one can add an option `noindentafter` to the package call or use `\titlespacing*` to remove this indentation. See this SE question: [Cancelling first-line indents after section titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36623/cancelling-first-line-indents-after-section-titles). I cannot find similar things for `sectsty`, nor has experimentation succeeded.

Why am I using `sectsty` then?
Well, I like the font and `sectionrule` options.
I have not been able to get the same font using `titlesec` and the `\titleformat` option---which is somewhat confusing to me. The command `\sectionrule` appears to be specific to `sectsty`.

Thus I would like one of the following solutions.

1. Obtain the same font and section rule using `titlesec`.
2. Remove the indentation using `sectsty`.

Option (1) would be preferable, but Option (2) is acceptable.

---

Two MWEs. The first is set up for `sectsty` and the second for `titlesec`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{%                      % Change font of \section command
    \noindent
    \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}%       % bch-b-n: CharterBT-Bold font
    \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{2pt}}
\subsectionfont{\noindent\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}}

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}
This is not indented

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section} {1}{\z@}%
    {\bigskipamount}%
    {\bigskipamount}%
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries\SS@sectfont}}
\makeatother
\section{Next Section}
This is indented now \texttt{:frowning:}

\end{document}
```

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
    {\sffamily \normalsize \bfseries \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}
This is not indented

\titlespacing{\section}
    {0pt}
    {\bigskipamount}
    {\medskipamount}
\section{Next Section}
This is indented now \texttt{:frowning:}

\titlespacing*{\section}
    {0pt}
    {\bigskipamount}
    {\medskipamount}
\section{Final Section}
But viola, it is no longer indented by adding \texttt{*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please post a small complete code, not just snippets?

Comment: Sure `:-)` -- personally I didn't feel it was beneficial in this case, but if you're offering to help then I'll certainly provide what you ask for! `:-)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a way to do what you want with titlesec. I took the liberty  to put `\titlespacing` in the preamble, to replace the Helvetica font with its clone TeX Gyre Heros, which has more glyphs and to reduce the spacing between section number and title to a half quad, which looks better, from my point of view.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[noindentafter]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
    {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n} \normalsize\boldmath}{\thesection}{0.5em}{}[{\titlerule[2pt]}]
\titlespacing{\section}
    {0pt}
    {\bigskipamount}
    {\medskipamount}

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}
This is not indented

\section{Next Section}%
This is \emph{not} indented now\texttt{:frowning:}

\section{Final Section}
But Viola, it is no longer indented by adding \texttt{*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I was also able to get something similar to what you have done adjusting my MWEs, but not answer my query in full. I found that `\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}` was different in the `sectsty` version compared with `titlesoc`.[*] More importantly, though, the `sectionrule` is missing. It is this which I was unable to get in `titletoc`... [*I notice now that I didn't include this font in the MWE. Naturally one can simply copy+paste it from one to the other though. The issue is the missing rule, which I was unable to include]

Comment: Btw, I only included the `\titlespacing` stuff _not_ in the preamble to demonstrate the different behaviour obtained by adding the `*` :)

Comment: @SamOT: I've added a rule command from titlesec – it has to be enclosed in a pair of braces, as its thickness is an optional argument, and it is placed in the last, optional argument of `\titleformat` Please see if it corresponds to what you want.

Comment: Thanks, it looks good! `\sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{2pt}` has spacing arguments---search for "sectionrule" in http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/sectsty/sectsty.pdf. How should I add this in? It should be quite easy, no...? Maybe some box that can be moved? :/

Comment: If I understand well, you also want a rule above the title?

Comment: No, sorry for not being clear! If you compare the positions between the `sectsty` version I gave and the `titlesec` version you gave, the spacings are a bit different. Obviously, one should make sure that the details `\large\bfseries` are the same in both cases

Comment: Basically, `sectionrule` has some spacing options which your `\titlerule` option doesn't _appear_ to have. I think that's not such a problem, though. Reading the documentation on `titlerule` gives some illumination :)

Comment: @SamOT: For the upper rule, you may use a standard \rule which has an optional argument for the vertical placement  of the rule, or package `xhfill`, which allows for customisation of `\hrulefill`.

Comment: Ah, I'm still not looking for it _above_. Just saying that it could be moved _up a little_. Either way, your solution is very helpful, thank you! `:-)`

Comment: I thought you wanted a pair of rules, one above the title, the other below. To move the rule below a bit, you can add  (in the final optional argument) a `\vskip -some length` before `\titlerule`.