# Vertical space between Chapter # and Chapter title

Tags: spacing

How we give a vertical gap of 25 mm between the Chapter number (#) and chapter
title lines and between chapter title line and the first paragraph.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Distance between chapter title and text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11233/5764); [Space length between the chapter number and the chapter title](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88025/5764)

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: I am using \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Space length between the chapter number and the chapter title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88025/5764), the spaces you're after are given in `\@makechapterhead` for `\chapter` (and `\@makeschapterhead` for `\chapter*`). The following definition(s) are taken from [`report.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls):

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@% <--- Chapter title & Chapter text
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@% <------- Chapter text and first paragraph
  }}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@% <------- Chapter text and first paragraph
  }}
```

These values can be patched/altered using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{20\p@}{25mm}{}{}% Correct \chapter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{40\p@}{25mm}{}{}% ... \chapter
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{40\p@}{25mm}{}{}% ... \chapter*
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter} Some text
\chapter*{Another chapter} Some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't effect. Why you are giving it two or three times. It is same for \chapter{} and \chapter*{}.

Comment: @DeepeshPatel: Each patch changes a single thing. The first does a search-and-replace of `20\p@` to `25mm` in `\@makechapterhead`. The second does a search-and-replace of `40\p@` to `25mm` in `\@makechapterhead`. The third does a search-and-replace of `40\p@` to `25mm` in `\@makeschapterhead`. Two different macros, three different search-and-replaces. Are you perhaps loading some sectioning package like [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)? Sectioning packages usually redefine these macros I'm trying to update, causing the search-and-replace to not work.