# Reducing vertical space between heading of Glossaries package

Tags: spacing, glossaries

I am using using a custom `.sty` file which uses `report` document class. For List of Acronyms, I am using `glossaries` package. The space after the heading of List of Acronyms and the first acronyms is litter more then what is it for List of figure and tables. I want to reduce this to be the same as the space after LOF and LOT.

[image: screenshot with mark]

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Distance between chapter title and text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11233/5764)

Comment: Try something like `\renewcommand*{\glossarypreamble}{\vspace*{-10pt}}`